# Manage AFNetworking multiple requests with AFHTTPClient enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests method

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, request, afnetworking

I want to create a table view slide menu like FB or Linkedin, I mean dynamically, so I have to make some requests at the same time. I am using AFNetworking. with a custom `AFHTTTPClient` which its called **YPLHTTPClients** and it is a **AFHTTPClient** subclass. In this class I have two methods. `SharedClient` and `initWithBaseURL`.

I also want to use `enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests` method in this class to return data to the viewController and create the tableView of my menu.

I would like to call a method who uses `enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests`this function in the client and return a dictionary or something with my information data, instead of do everything in the ViewController like I do here:

```
 NSMutableArray *mutableRequests = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *URLString in [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"users", @"intProjects", nil]) {
        [mutableRequests addObject:[[YPLHTTPClient sharedHTTPClient] requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:URLString parameters:nil]];
    }
    __block NSDictionary *parsedObject1, *parsedObject2;
    [[YPLHTTPClient sharedHTTPClient] enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests:mutableRequests progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfCompletedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
        NSLog(@"%lu of %lu Completed", (unsigned long)numberOfCompletedOperations, (unsigned long)totalNumberOfOperations);
    } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
        NSError *thisError;


         parsedObject1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[operations objectAtIndex:0] responseData] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&thisError];
        NSLog(@"Completion: %@", parsedObject1 );
        parsedObject2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[operations objectAtIndex:1] responseData] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&thisError];
        NSLog(@"Completion: %@", parsedObject2 );
```

I also would like to know, how can I show and Image while I am downloading this data.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but you can use something like [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) to show a progress bar that's updated in `progressBlock` (progress = numberOfCompletedOperations / totalNumberOfOperations).